# Using VB on excel, sum of column is only one cell

Tags: vb.net, excel, sum

```
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim lastcol As Integer, thiscol As Integer

    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\d3p823\Desktop\test data.xlsx") 'opens workbook'
    xlWsheet2 = xlWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4") 'set active sheet'
    xlApp.Visible = True

    With xlWsheet2
        lastrow = xlWsheet2.Cells(xlWsheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
        lastcol = xlWsheet2.Cells(1, xlWsheet2.Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column
        For thiscol = 2 To lastcol
            xlWsheet2.Cells(lastrow + 1, thiscol).Select()
            xlApp.ActiveCell.Value = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Sum(xlWsheet2.Cells(2, xlApp.ActiveCell.Column), xlApp.ActiveCell)
        Next
    End With
```

OK, so I've got a rectangular block of data on a spreadsheet that has row 1 and column 1 as labels (text and numbers), and data from cell(2,2) on. The data file will be variable in the number of rows and columns it has, but all the data is contiguous: no empty cells.  @Clif and I have come up with the above code to find the last row and column of data, and then sum up each column in the first empty cell beneath each column.

I don't get errors anymore, thank goodness, but the sums added into the first empty row aren't totaling the entire column, just the first cell.  This makes me think that the FOR-NEXT loop isn't progressing past the first iteration, but I can't see why that's occurring.

Comment: You are passing two individual cells to your `Sum`, rather than a Range.  Couple of other points: you create a With block then don't use it, and use of Select/ActiveCell is neither necessary nor desirable

Comment: @chrisneilsen, I tried to run the code without `Select` and `ActiveCell` just using `Cells(lastrow + 1, thiscol).Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), ActiveCell))` and it would not work. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Clif added answer to demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

- You are passing two individual cells to your Sum, rather than a Range.
- you create a With block then don't use it,
- use of Select/ActiveCell is neither necessary nor desirable
- use of `Integer` rather than `long`

…

```
With xlWsheet2
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row
    lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column
    For thiscol = 2 To lastcol
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, thiscol).Value = _
          xlApp.Sum(.Range(.Cells(2, thiscol), .Cells(lastrow, thiscol)))
    Next
End With
```

Comment: thanks!  This worked great.  I was battling the '.Cells' syntax the whole way with this.  VS Express just wouldn't give me enough of a hint.  I also got bogged down with the problem of generating property/method stubs for undefined variables, which I eventually got past.  I always had a WITH block in my code, here, but at one point, I tried defining everything specifically to see what effect that would have (and forgot to clean up once that didn't work).  There's a lot of help out there for the "A1" Excel reference style out there; not so much for the ".cell" syntax.

Comment: I am sure that it is just that I don't know enough about how the code should work, especially `With`, but when I run it, it stops at the second line, `lastrow =...` , with "Run-time error '424' Object required". I am also noticing that when I debug, the locals window is showing `xlSheet1` and `xlApp` as variables, type `Variant`. I am using Excel 2010 and my data is on the 1st tab, so I changed `xlWsheet2` to `xlWsheet1`, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Clif not really appropriate to hijack someone else's Q, but note that this is tagged `vb.net`, not `vba`.  If this is done in `vba` some of the details will be different, but the overall flow is the same.  Sounds like you need to add `Option Explicit` to your module to force declaration of _all_ your variables!

Comment: @chrisneilsen, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

- By declaring your variables as integers, you limit them to 32,768.  So if you are summing rows below that level, your macro will fail.
- Since you indicate your data area is contiguous, and rectangular, and starts at A1, you can just use CurrentRegion to obtain the range reference to your data area.
- For speed purposes, an operation like this will execute much more rapidly when done within a vba array, rather than on the worksheet.
- Some limited testing suggests looping to ADD executes more quickly (order of magnitude) than using the SUM worksheet function, at least on a limited data set. Whether that will
  be the case on your real data can only be resolved by testing.
- I would suggest something like the following (you will need to add code to open the workbook, and change the code setting the appropriate sheet)

-

```
Option Explicit
Sub AddColumns()
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim RNG As Range
    Dim V As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim dTemp As Double

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")

'with offset, we will skip the labels row, and leave
'  one blank at the end for the total
Set RNG = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Offset(rowoffset:=1)
V = RNG

For I = 2 To UBound(V, 2) 'The "2" to skip the first column
    dTemp = 0
    For J = 1 To UBound(V, 1) - 1
        dTemp = dTemp + V(J, I)
    Next J
    V(UBound(V), I) = dTemp
Next I

RNG = V

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You require a second `For` loop to go from row 2 to the `lastrow`.

Alternatively replace the statement before the `Next` statement with this

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & -lastrow + 1 & "]C:R[-1]C)"`

This uses the `SUM` function and eliminates the need for the second For loop.